# Memory Leak tool for PHP? Using LAMP

Tags: php, linux, memory-leaks

Anyone know a good tool for discovery of memleaks for PHP? I can use either client or server side. Thanks

Comment: You might want to check this question on ServerFault for trying to crack down on memory leaks: http://serverfault.com/questions/88997/how-can-i-determine-the-cause-of-an-apparent-memory-leak-in-my-apache-php-based-w

Comment: xdebug can output memory profiling information, but the format is hard to do anything with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/) and perhaps adding [xhprof](http://mirror.facebook.net/facebook/xhprof/doc.html).

Not hard to implement, easy to work and very nice way to visualize and find leaks (both in time and memory).

Comment: Time leaks? Is that when you waste your time on something and don't get it back?

Comment: It's the time which your function waste before return response (if returns at all).

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to manage memory for most applications. This isn't C. However, with that said, I'm assuming you have a good reason to need a memory leak detector in PHP. 
[This article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-v521/) explains memory usage in a slightly outdated (but still relevant) version of PHP. Scroll down to the "Memory management functions in PHP" section for built-in memory management functions.

Here's an overview of the most popular ones:

1. [memory_get_usage](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php): Gets the total bytes used by the current PHP script
2. [memory_get_peak_usage](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php): Gets the maximum bytes used by the current PHP script
3. [ini_get('memory_limit')](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php): Gets the maximum amount of bytes allowed by the current PHP script

Comment: In practice, this is what I end up doing when I have mem issues.  Stick `memory_get_usage` calls all over the place.  Haven't found anything easier to use.

Comment: Aye, I used that, but  don't have acess to all the code used, so I needed a external debugging tool. But `memory_get_usage` helped a lot, thanks!